# Need to understand syntax in C program

Tags: c, syntax

I have been tasked with studying and modifying a C program. Generally, I write code in pl/sql, but not C. I have been able to decipher most of the code, but the program flow is still eluding me. After looking up several C references guides, I am not understanding how the C code works. I'm hoping someone here can answer a few syntax questions and tell me what each statement is trying to do.

Here is one sample, with my guesses below.

```
    input(ask_fterm,TM_NLS_Get("0004","FROM TERM: "),6,ALPHA);
    if ( !*ask_fterm ) goto opt_fterm;
    tmstrcpy(fterm,ask_fterm);
    goto nextparmb;
  opt_fterm:
    tmstrcpy(parm_no,_TMC("02"));
    sel_optional_ind(FIRST_ROW);
    if ( compare(rpt_optional_ind,_TMC("O"),EQS) ) goto nextparmb;
    goto missing_parms;
```

First, I don't understand !*.  What does the exclamation asterisk combination?
Second I assume that if must be ended with endif, unless it is on a single line?
Third tmstrcopy() apparently copies the value of the 2nd parameter into the 1st parameter?

I also have several parameters which I don't understand. I'm hoping someone gives me a hint.

```
tmstrcpy(valid_ind,_TMC("N"));
 input(ask_toterm,TM_NLS_Get("0005","TO TERM: "),6,ALPHA);
```

I don't know where to find _TMC  and TM_NLS_Get.

Comment: `!*` isn't a single operator, it's applying `!` to `*ask_fterm`. `endif` doesn't exist in C (`#endif` does, but that's preprocessor stuff and isn't relevant here).

Comment: That's really awful C code, by the way.  I'm not against the strategic use of a well-placed `goto` (unlike some people), but those nine lines contain four `goto`s and one label, for no good reason that I can see.  It is exactly the kind of spaghetti code that gives `goto` (in any language) a bad name.

Answer (score 0):

> First, I don't understand !*. What does the exclamation asterisk combination?

That's two separate operators.  `!` is logical negation. Unary `*` is for dereferencing a pointer.  Put together, they each have their separate effect, so `!*ask_fterm` means determine the value of the object to which pointer `ask_fterm` points (this is `*`); if that value is 0 then the result is 1, else the result is 0 (this is `!`).  If `ask_fterm` is a pointer to the first character of a string, then that's a check for whether the string is empty (zero-length), because C strings are terminated by a character with value 0.

> Second I assume that if must be ended with endif, unless it is on a single line?

There is no endif in C.  An `if` construct controls exactly one statement, but that can be and often is a compound one (which you can recognize by the `{` and `}` delimiters enclosing it).  There may also be an `else` clause, also controlling exactly one statement, which can be a compound one.

> Third tmstrcopy() apparently copies the value of the 2nd parameter into the 1st parameter?

That appears to be a user-defined function.  It is certainly not from the C standard library.  If I were to guess based on the name and usage, I would guess that it copies a *trimmed* version of the string to which the right-hand argument points into the space to which the left-hand argument points.

> I don't know where to find _TMC and TM_NLS_Get.

Those are not standard C features.  Possibly they are recognized directly by your C implementation, or possibly they are macros defined earlier in the file or in one of the header files it includes.